# Determine the number of ordered pairs of integers $(m, n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine the number of ordered pairs of integers $(m, n)$ for which $mn\geq 0$ and
$m^3+n^3+99mn=33^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$m^3 + n^3 + 99 m n - 33^3 = \left( m+n-33 \right)  \left( {m}^{2}-mn+{n}^{2}+33\,m+33\,n+1089 \right) 
$$

Comment: Just to provide more detail to Robert's answer $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$